# Pigeonhole Principle - prove that average of 4 integers = average of 2

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle

Let S be a set of 10 distinct integers between −10 and 10 (inclusive). Prove that there exist four distinct integers in S whose average is the same as the average of just two of the four.

Comment: So where are you having difficulty applying the pigeonhole principle?

Answer (score 4):

HINT: The key is to realize that it’s enough to prove that there are two different pairs of integers from $S$ that have the same average. Now you have to figure out

- why that’s enough, and
- why it’s true.